# How to stop Twitter Bootstrap video on window load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

am using Twitter Bootstrap Video

```
 <section class="col-md-6 video-left">
                    <div class="flex-video widescreen" style="margin: 0 auto;">
                    <iframe id="video-home" name="video-home" allowfullscreen="" src="viedos/<?php  echo  $homecontents['Homecontent']['video']?>" frameborder="0"></iframe>
                    </div> 
                </section>
```

Issue: video auto-play , when I load my page. I want to stop it.
I'm not suppose to upload video at you-tube. 
Below is the solution with youtube url.

src="//www.youtube.com/embed/AfjuNRjzZnE?rel=0&autoplay=0&wmode=opaque"

In my case video is coming from local path(feteching from database i.e "short-sample-video.mp4").
Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Can you give a `$homecontents['Homecontent']['video']` example url

Comment: $homecontents['Homecontent']['video']//By this line of code,I just taking url from the database.

Comment: Provide an example URL please

Comment: Sorry.. Its only a dummy video short-sample-video.mp4..not a url

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you try and inject the video after the dom is loaded.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
       $(".widescreen").html( // Video here );
    });
</script>
```

Alternatively, give us the video URL and I can create a fiddle.

Comment: Tyler: I am not using any url, just sample viedo (i.e short-sample-video.mp4)